# How to sum fields in a view Qweb? Odoo 14

Tags: python, xml, odoo

how can sum 2 values in qweb ?
I want to add span with the sum values of field1 + field2.

```
<span t-field="doc.field1"/>
 <span t-field="doc.field2"/>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
<t t-set="total" t-value="doc.field1 + doc.field2"/>
```

Now you can use total variable for display.

For example:

```
<span t-esc="total"/>
```